# Python large DataFrame - calculate standard deviation of expanding returns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, pandas-groupby

I am currently working with a super large dataframe (CRSP Daily Stock File), which consists of daily returns for over 16k firms with 8.5m lines of data in total. Running a for loop would take about 2 weeks in Python.

The goal is to calculate the volatility of returns (standard deviation) for every firm. For every month-end I need the standard deviation of returns from the beginning of a that year up to that month. I tried to visualise what I mean in a graph (green=example for standard deviation of August datapoint):
[image]

My input DataFrame is shown in the next picture. "PERMNO" is the firm identifier, "date" is date of the daily return, and "RETX" ist the daily return.

[image]

The output data frame should be only in monthly frequency. So, 12 standard deviations in one year for each company.

I tried using Pandas .groupby functionality and combining with .expanding() in each year. Problem might be that I don't get the point with the datetime format of the date column. With that I only get the std for the expanding period of all the previous dates (incl. previous years).

```
df.groupby("PERMNO").expanding().std()
```

There might be a simple solution with Pandas' built in functions such as .expanding(), .groupby(), .apply() etc. with which one can avoid using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand that the standard deviation is based on the daily returns which you have already got in the DataFrame. Let me know if I am wrong on this.

1. Convert to Time Series DataFrame

The best way to do this is to convert all data to a Timeseries DataFrame:

## Convert values in date column to datetime format

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

## Convert the 'date' column to DatetimeIndex

```
df = df.set_index(df['date'])
df.drop('date', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

[image: set the date column to DatetimeIndex by data2wealth]

[image: check the type of the DatetimeIndex by data2wealth]

## Extract Jan data and calculate std

```
df_1 = df['01/01/2020':'01/31/2020']
std_1 = df_1['RETX'].std()
```

[image: Sliced Jan data from Timeseries DataFrame by data2wealth]

[image: slice the Timeseries DataFrame by data2wealth]

## Extract Jan to Feb data and calculate std

```
df_2 = df['01/01/2020':'02/29/2020']
std_2 = df_1['RETX'].std()
```

## ... ...

## Extract Jan to Dec data and calculate std

```
df_12 = df['01/01/2020':'12/31/2020']
std_12 = df_12['RETX'].std()
```

2. Efficiency

Even though you have got 8.5m lines of code, they were only for 16k tickers which Python would be able to calculate std pretty quick if you covert to Time Series DateFrame, as every calculation only takes out data from a specific time frame which is very efficient.

3. groupby() function

I believe the DataFrame you showed had already been grouped using `df.groupby('ticker')`
so I didn't demonstrate this part of code.

Extra comment on groupby() function added on 8th Mar 2022:

I suggest slicing the desired timeframe for each ticker first, and then use concat() to store the sliced data in one DataFrame. After that use groupby() function to get std in one go, no need to loop:

```
df_Jan_Dec_2020.groupby('ticker').agg(['count','min','max','mean','std','var'])
```

[image: groupby() function for dataframe]

I create a Jupyter Notebook example and generated some random price data with exactly the same date range you showed above. It's uploaded to my public GitHub, feel free to download it and play around. Good luck and have fun!

[The Jupyter Notebook file on my GitHub](https://github.com/data2wealth/StackOverflow.git)

[My blog](https://medium.com/@data2wealth)

Comment: The date column already is in datetime format. I understand all the slicing part of your code, but not the implementation for the whole dataframe. So you would still suggest running a loop e.g. an iteration for every month of any firm. But how do you make use of the date time format to only consider certain month in a loop and combine it with groupby? My result should be the std_1, std_2, etc. data frames for every year of any firm.

Comment: I suggest slicing the desired timeframe for each ticker first, and then use concat() to store the sliced data in one DataFrame. After that use groupby() function to get std in one go, no need to loop: df_Jan_Dec_2020.groupby('ticker').agg(['count','min','max','mean','std','var'])